# Retrieve references to functions registered via atexit() 

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, atexit

For functions registered using `atexit()`: Is it possible to retrieve references to them, to call them directly?

Although this is meant as a general question, solutions regarding the use of `gcc`/`glibc` are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in any portable way, no. The list of registered functions is owned by the runtime library, and there is no interface to access it.

For glibc specifics as per your comment, the exit handlers are implemented by [exit.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/exit.c;h=2235990285f80c7482d2dcc7dcd92463967f4eb1;hb=HEAD) and [exit.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdlib/exit.h;h=d5013218a67bd308572e85daa45bc9fb3640765f;hb=HEAD). I haven't studied them intensely enough to figure out of it's possible to drill through the abstraction/data hiding. You might need to e.g. include glibc-specific headers that probably aren't generally available, for instance.

Comment: Ah, this sounds interesting. So I added the `glibc` tag, and kindly ask you whether this library offers a way to access the functions in question.

Answer (score 2):

No. However, if you have control over all the code in the application, you could maintain a list yourself, and register a single function to the real `atexit()` which would run through the list when the system is terminated.